# Show only facts in Excel's show fields dropdown when using tabular cube

Tags: excel, ssas, powerpivot, cube, ssas-tabular

When having a connection to a multidimensional cube in Excel (powerpivot table) there is an option to Show fields and select only one fact and its related dimensions.

Here is what I mean

[image: Excel powerpivot show fields option]

This shows only the facts from the model.

**BUT**

When using connection to a tabular cube, this option shows ALL dimensions and facts (not even ordered in any way) like this:

[image: show fields in excel tabular cube]

**The question**

Is there any chance of hiding the dimensions?
In the multidim cube this works thanks to defining perspectives. I have defined perspectives in the same way in the tabular cube as well but it still shows everything in excel

Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you ever soulve this problem? We are moving from multi-dimensional to tabular and this is one thing that i would like to present to end users as it was in multi-dimensional.

Comment: @RemkovanHierden Unfortunately not :( It's an Excel thing...

Answer (score 0):

On Excel you may select the perspective (if exists) in the get Data process instead of the whole Model. 
Excel will only show the dimensions included in that perspective.

If you want to hide the dimension from any client tool there is an option on VS: Select the table -> properties -> [Hidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/table-properties-ssas-tabular?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes that could be a workaround but not for our case here... :)

Comment: It's weird because my dimensions and facts appear ordered. Also when I select a FactTable only related dimensions and Measures appear. (SSAS 2017 on excel 2016)

Comment: Yes it works when I select a fact table, it shows only related dimensions but my question is how can I hide dimensions from the dropwdown list. There are around 15 dimensions and 5-6 bridge tables that should be just hidden there

Comment: You can hide tables from client on Visual Studio, see my answer

Comment: Yes I know that too but this is not what I am trying. 
If you look at the screenshots, do they make sense?